# How can I add Explanatory text with Table in Latex

Tags: tables

I want to create a table which contains an explanatory text like the following picture:

[image]

here is the code I have written:

```
\begin{table}[]
\caption{N-best examples from the MSCOCO test set. Bold lines indicate a
novel sentence not present in the training set.}
\label{table3}
\centering
\resizebox{.90\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\toprule
A man throwing a frisbee in a park                         \\
\textbf{A man throwing a frisbee in a park}                \\
\textbf{A man standing in the grass with a frisbee.}       \\
A close up of a sandwich on a plate.                       \\
A close up of a plate of food with french fries.           \\
A white plate topped with a cut in half sandwich.          \\
A display case filled with lots of donuts.                 \\
\textbf{A display case filled with lots of cakes.}         \\
\textbf{A bakery display case filled with lots of donuts.} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

How can I get the bottom lines in this table? I have tried `\threeparttable`, but it seems to generate error. Can anyone show how it can be done?

Comment: Why not just add it as a table line after `\bottomrule`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please be so kind and extend your code fragment to complete but small document with your table. Try to show us how you try to use `threeparttable`. Help us to help you!

Answer (score 2):

In lack of any information about your document, I was able to write the following code for your table:

**Edit:**
 From my test bed I add relevant package and form an MWE that anyone can test proposed solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelfont=up,labelsep=newline, skip=1ex]{caption}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{N-best examples from the MSCOCO test set.}
\label{table3}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \toprule
A man throwing a frisbee in a park                         \\
\textbf{A man throwing a frisbee in a park}                \\
\textbf{A man standing in the grass with a frisbee.}       \\
A close up of a sandwich on a plate.                       \\
A close up of a plate of food with french fries.           \\
A white plate topped with a cut in half sandwich.          \\
A display case filled with lots of donuts.                 \\
\textbf{A display case filled with lots of cakes.}         \\
\textbf{A bakery display case filled with lots of donuts.} \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]\itshape
Bold Lines Indicate a Novel Setence not Present in the Training set
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which using my testbed gives:

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Yes, That is what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, good to know! When you will extend your code fragment to complete small document that I will be able to complete my answer?